# ssh from windows 10 to debian with no password

Tags: windows-10, ssh, debian, openssh

I tried to SSH without a password from a Windows 10 client to a Linux [Debian] server without using a password, following every step described [here](https://codefaq.org/server/how-to-ssh-login-without-password-on-windows-10/); however, I am still asked for the password every time I want to login:

- `ssh -v root@192.168.137.121`:

  ```ini
  OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

  debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config
  debug1: Connecting to 192.168.137.121 [192.168.137.121] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.

  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
  debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1

  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000

  debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.137.121:22 as 'root'
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
  debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
  debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
  debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:WCidk4fQas5o/UxDIOHdswBHGHdDZSXcySySpEm0Rp8
  debug1: Host '192.168.137.121' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:9aF1rpTcWnj2ADGL/FpO0Gsgjh13zND14oRT1sfzeoU agent
  debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_ed25519
  debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_xmss
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:9aF1rpTcWnj2ADGL/FpO0Gsgjh13zND14oRT1sfzeoU agent
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
  debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_ed25519
  debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_xmss

  debug1: Next authentication method: password
  debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
  ```
- `ect/ssh/sshd_config`:

  ```ini
  #cat sshd_config
  # Package generated configuration file
  # See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

  Port 22

  Protocol 2
  # HostKeys for protocol version 2
  HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
  HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
  HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
  HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

  UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

  # Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
  KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
  ServerKeyBits 1024

  SyslogFacility AUTH
  LogLevel INFO

  LoginGraceTime 120
  PermitRootLogin yes
  StrictModes yes

  RSAAuthentication yes
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  #AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

  IgnoreRhosts yes
  RhostsRSAAuthentication no
  HostbasedAuthentication no
  #IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

  PermitEmptyPasswords no

  ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

  #PasswordAuthentication yes

  X11Forwarding yes
  X11DisplayOffset 10
  PrintMotd no
  PrintLastLog yes
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  #UseLogin no

  #MaxStartups 10:30:60
  #Banner /etc/issue.net

  AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

  Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

  UsePAM yes
  ```
- `%UserProfile%\.ssh`:

  ```ini
  Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
  ----                 -------------         ------ ----
  -a----         4/26/2022   8:59 AM            133 config
  -a----         4/20/2022   1:27 PM           2602 id_rsa
  -a----         4/20/2022   1:27 PM            569 id_rsa.pub
  -a----         4/25/2022   5:45 PM            178 known_hosts
  ```
- **Left:** Debian server's `root/.ssh/id_rsa-pub` 
   **Right:** Windows 10 client's: `~\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` 
   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: On second thought it looks like your private key was not found in any of the locations the SSH client looks for them (indicated by the "type -1" messages) and ssh defaults to password login. I've removed my previous answer.

Comment: can you list the files there is in ```C:\Users\user\.ssh/``` ?

Comment: @dominix, I added it to the post

Comment: Please post the `sshd_config`

Comment: @JW0914, Do you mean the config file inside the .ssh directory? It is empty

Comment: By "following every step", do you mean you can actually log in *with password as root* via ssh?

Comment: @TomYan, yes this I can

Comment: Make sure you have `.ssh/authorized_keys` under `/root/` but not e.g. `ssh/authorise_key`.

Comment: @TomYan, I have /root/.ssh/authorized_keys with an "s" at the end

Comment: and does your distant ```/root/.ssh/authorized_keys``` really content your user ```%UserProfile%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub```  ? (try to ```ssh root@192.168.137.121 "cat -A .ssh/authorized_keys"```  to ensure there is not bad formatted chars).

Comment: @dominix, I added the content. It looks like they are the same

Comment: OK, can you check the rights and the mod of /root  and /root/.ssh they should be 700 and /root/.ssh/authorized_keys should be 0600

```     ls -ld /root /root/.ssh ls -ld /root /root/.ssh /root/.ssh/authorized_keys 
    drwx------ 13 root root 4096 avril 26 16:44 /root
    drwx------  2 root root 4096 oct.   7  2021 /root/.ssh
    -rw-------  1 root root 2168 mai   11  2020 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
 ```

Comment: @dominix, the command `stat -c "%a %n"` applied on the different directories and file return 700 for `/root`, 700 for `/root/.ssh` and 600 for `/authorized_keys`

Comment: The [`sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) controls authentication and is why I asked for it to be added to the question _(it can be found within `/etc/ssh`)_. There's no way to determine the issue without that config; however, what is clear is the RSA key on the Windows client either doesn't match the public key stored on the Debian server's user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` or it's excluded in the server's config. The former is easy to fix by `cat`'ing the public key's output to the server's `authorized_keys` _(sometimes encoding creates an issue with copy/paste)_

Comment: @JW0914, okay I added the content of the file

Comment: `ssh_config` != `sshd_config`

Comment: @TomYan Oh, right, I added `sshd_config` as well

Comment: @roi_saumon `sshd_config`: Uncomment `#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys` and comment out `UsePAM yes`. While having no bearing on this, how old is the OpenSSH installation on the Debian server, as `RSAAuthentication` and `ServerKeyBits` was depreciated years ago IIRC _(it's not even on the man page any more)_; for a secure `sshd_config`, please see [this](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH/BSD-Linux/sshd_config) example.

Comment: @JW0914, I tried to comment and uncomment what you suggested but it didn't work. The output of `ssh -V` gave me `OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016`

Comment: @roi_saumon Did you restart the OpenSSH server after doing so and put the contents of the client's SSH key into the server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file? Your issue is a result of the OpenSSH server not being properly configured to use SSH keys, as in the `sshd_config`, `AuthorizedKeysFile` was commented out and `UsePAM` was enabled when you're not using a **P**lugable **A**uthentation **M**odule, combined with it doesn't appear as though the public key was added to the server's `authorized_keys` file. I would also recommend updating the OpenSSH server, as you're using a 6yr old version.

Comment: @roi_saumon _(Cont'd...)_ If resolving the key issue still doesn't allow logging in, you'll need to update OpenSSH on the server, as that would be the only other issue and it's pointless trying to troubleshoot a no longer supported version of OpenSSH that's as old as the one you're using since so much has changed and been depreciated; it's also lacking 6yrs of security updates. Once updated, the `sshd_config` may need to be updated _(see prior linked to example)_, since severa options currently used are depreciated. I can create an answer once you've verified resolving the aforementioned works

Comment: @JW0914, I tried to comment and uncomment what you suggested but it did not work. How do you update openSSH? I did `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` but it seems it doesn't upgrade anything since `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`. I am not sure how these things work

Comment: @roi_saumon That's odd, unless you're using an obsolete version of Debian? Try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install openssh-server` or use `apt` to search for `openssh`. As to the public key authentication issue, please re-read my second-to-last comment, as it's more than just the commenting out/uncommenting those two options since the server hasn't ben configured for OpenSSH public key authentication, which is why you can't log in with a public key _(e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa-pub` is for the server connecting as a client, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is where the Win10 client's public key goes)_